# Datastore Emulator creates empty index.yaml - remote Firebase raises error while local does not

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

- Google App Engine in Node.js on Windows 10
- I use Googles Datastore emulator for local development according to
  this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator).
- I use this [Node.js tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-datastore) to create and query data in Datastore.

When I use the local emulator everything works fine. When I use the remote Datastore from my local project I get this error message:

```
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (C:\Users\Code\google-cloud\nodejs-docs-samples\appengine\datastore\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:30:26)
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (C:\Users\Code\google-cloud\nodejs-docs-samples\appengine\datastore\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:96:33)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at process.nextTick (C:\Users\Code\google-cloud\nodejs-docs-samples\appengine\datastore\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:97:22)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

An index is supposed to be created while running the emulator in directory `~gcloud\emulators\datastore\WEB-INF\index.yaml`. The file is empty after running the emulator and running the query from the project:

app.js

```
/**
 * Retrieve the latest 10 visit records from the database.
 */
const getVisits = () => {
  const query = datastore
    .createQuery('visit')
    .order('timestamp', {descending: true})
    .limit(10);

  return datastore.runQuery(query);
};
```

index.yaml

```
indexes:
# AUTOGENERATED

# This index.yaml is automatically updated whenever the Cloud Datastore
# emulator detects that a new type of query is run. If you want to manage the
# index.yaml file manually, remove the "# AUTOGENERATED" marker line above.
# If you want to manage some indexes manually, move them above the marker line.
```

I understand that the remote database has no index which causes the error from above. I have run the query from the project several times but the index is not updated.

I have tried uploading the index.yaml but because there is nothing apart from comments the error continues.

**How can I generate the index so the remote Datastore works without error?**

Comment: Are you setting --data-dir on the emulator command line?  If so, that's where the index.yaml file would end up.

Comment: @JimMorrison No, I do not set --data-dir. The emulator uses the default folder location which is `C:\Users\Code\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\emulators\datastore\WEB-INF`

Comment: Can you show the code building and running the query? There are cases in which the built-in indexes appear to be usable in a 'zig-zag' scheme, but sometimes that takes too long and eventually the queries fail, asking for a composite index.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I added the code for the query "Retrieve the latest 10 visit records from the database." from the tutorial that is supposed to create the index automatically.

Comment: That's a query with no filters and only one sort order on a property, [builtin indexes should be sufficient](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#index_configuration). This explains why you have no index in the local index.yaml file. Something else is going on. Do you see the index in Serving state for your project in the Cloud Console?

Comment: Was a `visit` entity ever been created in that project?

Comment: Try going to http://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities on your project.  There is a chance you set up your database in Firestore native mode which uses different indexes.